# overloading methods based on implicits

Tags: scala

i wrote this code

```
trait Pet
case class Dog() extends Pet
case class Cat() extends Pet
def foo(i: Int)(implicit d: Dog) = println("dog")
def foo(i: Int)(implicit c: Cat) = println("cat")
def doFoo(a: Pet) = {
  a match {
    case a: Dog => implicit val dog : Dog = a; foo(10)
    case a: Cat => implicit val cat : Cat = a; foo(10)
    case _ => println("unknown")
  }
}
```

I get an error

```
cmd0.sc:8: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method foo in object cmd0 of type (i: Int)(implicit c: $sess.cmd0.Cat)Unit
and  method foo in object cmd0 of type (i: Int)(implicit d: $sess.cmd0.Dog)Unit
match argument types (Int)
    case a: Dog => implicit val dog : Dog = a; foo(10)
                                               ^
cmd0.sc:9: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method foo in object cmd0 of type (i: Int)(implicit c: $sess.cmd0.Cat)Unit
and  method foo in object cmd0 of type (i: Int)(implicit d: $sess.cmd0.Dog)Unit
match argument types (Int)
    case a: Cat => implicit val cat : Cat = a; foo(10)
```

But why does it feel that there is ambiguity ... because in my first case match there is an implicit val dog and in my second case match there is an implicit val cat. So it should find the right implicits.

why is it not resolving correctly?

My environment is

```
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 0.8.2
(Scala 2.12.1 Java 1.8.0_121)
                                           ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler uses only the first parameter group to disambiguate overloaded methods.

```
def foo(x:Int)(y:Long): Long = y
def foo(x:Int)(y:Short): Short = y
foo(9)(2L)  // Error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition
```

-- **update** --

You've simplified your code example to the point that it's a little hard to tell what you're actually trying to achieve. Would this get at what you're after?

```
trait Pet {def foo(i: Int): Unit}
case class Dog() extends Pet {def foo(i: Int): Unit = println("dog")}
case class Cat() extends Pet {def foo(i: Int): Unit = println("cat")}

def doFoo(a: Pet) = a match {
  case d: Dog => d.foo(10)
  case c: Cat => c.foo(10)
  case _ => println("unknown")
}
```

Comment: is there a workaround, or some other way to give a hint to the compiler. and get what I want above.

Comment: use a typeclass

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch; Don't know if this update will address your needs or not.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch :) implicit parameters give you a better (more powerful) ad-hoc polymorphism compared to overloading, so combining this two features looks pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

**@jwvh answer is the right answer.**

Following Seth Tisue recommendation, here is the implementation of this problem (assuming I got your requirements right) using a type class:

```
trait Pet[A] {
  def name: String
}

object Pet {
   def create[A](n: String) = new Pet[A] { def name = n }
}


case class Dog()
object Dog {
   implicit val dogIsPet = Pet.create[Dog]("dog")
}

case class Cat()
object Cat {
    implicit val catIsPet = Pet.create[Cat]("cat")
}

def foo[A](i: A)(implicit p: Pet[A]) = p.name
```

Then you can use foo like this:

```
@ foo(Dog())
res5: String = "dog"
@ foo(Cat())
res6: String = "cat"
```